# weak linking in shared object not working as expected

Tags: c, unit-testing, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, weak-linking

I'm trying to use the [cmocka](https://cmocka.org/) unit test framework which suggests to use weak linking to be able to select a user-defined implementation over the actual implementation of a function. In my environment I have a shared object which I want to unit test. I've implemented the unit tests in a separate file which I compile and link to the shared object. My problem is that calling a function `bar` in the shared object which in turn calls a function `foo` in that shared object always leads to the real implementation of `foo` and not the custom one. I've created a simplified implementation of the shared object and of the unit test.

The shared library, `a.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void); __attribute__((weak))
void bar(void); __attribute__((weak))

void foo(void) {
    printf("called real foo\n");
}

void bar(void) {
    printf("called real bar calling\n");
    foo();
}
```

The unit test, `b.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool orig_foo;
bool orig_bar;

void __wrap_foo(void) {
    printf("in foo wrapper\n");
    if (orig_foo)
            __real_foo();
    else
            printf("called wrapped foo\n");
}

void __wrap_bar() {
    printf("in bar wrapper\n");
    if (orig_bar)
            __real_bar();
    else
            printf("called wrapped bar\n");
}

int main(void) {

    orig_bar = true;
    orig_foo = false;

    printf("calling foo from main\n");
    foo();

    printf("\n");

    printf("calling bar from main\n");
    bar();

    return 0;
}
```

And finally, the `Makefile`:

```
all: a.out

a.out: b.c a.so
    gcc -Wall b.c a.so -Wl,--wrap=foo -Wl,--wrap=bar

a.so: a.c
    gcc -Wall -c a.c -shared -o a.so

clean:
    rm -f a.so a.out
```

Running `a.out` produces the following output:

```
# ./a.out
calling foo from main
in foo wrapper
called wrapped foo

calling bar from main
in bar wrapper
called real bar
called real foo
```

From main, the direct call to `foo` results in `__wrap_foo` being called, as expected.

Next, I call `bar` from main which correctly results in `__wrap_bar` being called, where I redirect the call to the real implementation of `bar` (`__real_bar`). `bar` then calls `foo` but the real implementation is used, not the wrapped one. Why isn't the wrapped implementation of `foo` called in this case? It looks like the issue is related to from where the function call originates.

In function `bar`, if I replaced the called to `foo` with `__wrap_foo` I do get the expected behaviour however I don't think that this is an elegant solution.

I've managed to bypass this problem using normal linking and `dlopen(3)` and friends however I'm curious as to why weak linking isn't working in my case.

Comment: Weak attributes in shared library code are broken.

Comment: Makefile line for `a.so` is completely broken. You create an object file instead of a shared library.

Comment: Indeed, I fixed the makefile producing `a.so` from `a.o` (compiled with `-fpic`) but I get the exact same behaviour.

Comment: My example works if I split `foo` and `bar` into separate files and compile everything together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `bar()` the linker does **not** store a reference to `foo()` but to an offset in the `text` section of the translation unit. Therefore the name is lost.

The "weak" attribute does **not** help here.

Also it does not help to use `-ffunction_sections` because the reference will be to an offset of the section of `foo()`.

One straight forward way to get the desired result is to separate all functions in their own translation unit. You don't need separated source files for this, some conditional compilation will also help. But it makes the source ugly.

You might like to look into [my answer to the question "Rename a function without changing its references"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58460840/rename-a-function-without-changing-its-references/58461842#58461842), too.

Answer (score 1):

Ld's `--wrap` works by replacing calls to real functions by calls to their wrappers only in files which are linked with this flag. Your library isn't, so it just does plain `foo` and `bar` calls. So they get resolved to where they are implemented (`a.so`).

As for weak symbols, dynamic linker ignores their weakness and treats them as normal symbols (unless you run with `LD_DYNAMIC_WEAK` which isn't recommended).

In your particular case (overriding symbols in shared library) you'd probably need to apply `--wrap` to `a.so` as well. Or - you could use standard symbol interposition. Say if library-under-test is in `libsut.so` and you want to replace some functions with custom implementations in `libstub.so`, link them to driver program in a proper order:

```
LDFLAGS += -lstub -lsut
```

Then definitions in `libstub.so` will prevail over `libsut.so` ones.

Comment: Adding `--wrap` when building `a.so` didn't help, nor did defining `LD_DYNAMIC_WEAK=`. I'm already using symbol interpolation which works fine, it's the weak linking I'm trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

One error is that attribute syntax is not correct. Correct ones:

```
void foo(void) __attribute__((weak));
void bar(void) __attribute__((weak));
```

---

An alternative solution would be the standard Linux function interposition:

```
// a.c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void) {
    printf("called real foo\n");
}

void bar(void) {
    printf("called real bar calling\n");
    foo();
}
```

```
// b.c

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool orig_foo;
bool orig_bar;

void foo(void) {
    printf("in foo wrapper\n");

    static void(*__real_foo)(void);
    if(!__real_foo)
        __real_foo = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "foo");

    if (orig_foo)
            __real_foo();
    else
            printf("called wrapped foo\n");
}

void bar() {
    printf("in bar wrapper\n");

    static void(*__real_bar)(void);
    if(!__real_bar)
        __real_bar = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "bar");

    if (orig_bar)
            __real_bar();
    else
            printf("called wrapped bar\n");
}

int main(void) {

    orig_bar = true;
    orig_foo = false;

    printf("calling foo from main\n");
    foo();

    printf("\n");

    printf("calling bar from main\n");
    bar();

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -o a.so -shared -Wall -Wextra -fPIC a.c
$ gcc -o b -Wall -Wextra b.c -L. -l:a.so -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN' -ldl 
$ ./b
calling foo from main
in foo wrapper
called wrapped foo

calling bar from main
in bar wrapper
called real bar calling
in foo wrapper
called wrapped foo
```

Comment: Indeed the attribute syntax is incorrect however even by correcting it the problem persists.

Regarding dlsym, that's what how I had solved it however I'm still trying to figure out why weak linking isn't working.